# Variable Assignment Not Working With Switch Parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm doing something that seems pretty basic to me but is not working as expected.

If the script is run with the -WhatIf switch then $liveTest should be "Test".
If the script is run with the -Live switch then $liveTest should be "Live".

However both switches are causing $liveTest to be "Test"

```
param (
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsersOnlyLive')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsersOnlyTest')]
    [Switch]
    $users,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ComputersOnlyLive')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ComputersOnlyTest')]
    [Switch]
    $computers,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'AllLive')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'AllTest')]
    [Switch]
    $all,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $days,

    [switch]
    $console,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'AllTest')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsersOnlyTest')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ComputersOnlyTest')]
    [switch]
    $WhatIf,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'AllLive')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsersOnlyLive')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ComputersOnlyLive')]
    [switch]
    $live
)
Process {

    # If -WhatIf or -Live switch is passed, creates a hashtable for the -WhatIf parameter.
    If($WhatIf) { 
        $whatIf = @{ WhatIf = $true }
        $liveTest = "Test"
    }
    ElseIf($live) { 
        $whatIf = @{ WhatIf = $false }
        $liveTest = "Live"
    }
    If($liveTest = "Test"){Write-Output $liveTest}
    elseif($liveTest = "Live"){Write-Output $liveTest}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You conditions are using assignment rather than comparison operators. `If($liveTest = "Test")` needs to become `If($liveTest -eq "Test")`

Comment: You didn't get even an error message while using wrong assignment operator!

Comment: I did not, I don't know if that's normal or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` and `elseif` conditions are using the assignment operator `=` rather than comparison operator `-eq`. As a result, `$liveTest` is getting set to `Test` on each run. Update your code to the following:

```
if ($liveTest -eq "Test") {
    Write-Output $liveTest
}
elseif ($liveTest -eq "Live") {
    Write-Output $liveTest
}
```

Since you are using `if` and `elseif` conditions to do variable assignment, `$liveTest = "Test"` always happens and `$liveTest = "Live"` never happens.

See [About_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) for more information.

Comment: As always, thank you for taking the time to help me learn.  I'll read the link you posted.